# Animation for folding dropdown content after deactivating their display

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have successfully created the unfolding animation for my drop down content when they are first being displayed, but I can't figure out how to add the *folding* animation for smoother view when I remove display. Here are some the scripts (html part is huge so i will reduce it for demonstration purposes)(also will remove the id and innerHTML of them for privacy reasons, sorry)

HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn" onclick="dropDown('removed')">removed</button>
<div class="dropdown_content" id="removed">
<a class="page" href="html_files/dataset83_removed.html" target="docWindow">removed</a>
<a class="page" href="html_files/dataset84_removed.html" target="docWindow">removed</a>
</div>
</li>
<li class="dropdown">
<button class="dropbtn" onclick="dropDown('removed')">removed</button>
<div class="dropdown_content" id="removed">
<a class="page" href="html_files/dataset85_removed.html" target="docWindow">removed</a>
</div>
</li>
```

CSS:

```
/* dropdown button */
.dropbtn {
   
  color: black;
  background-color: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: thin solid darkgray;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* position dropdown content on <div> */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
}

/* dropdown content */
.dropdown_content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color:orange;
  top: 100%;
  right: -15px;
  border-top: thin solid black;
  border-bottom: thin solid black;
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  border-right: thin solid black;
  width: 225px;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.dropdown_content:last-child {
  border-bottom: none;
}

/* anchors */
.dropdown_content a {
  color: black;
  border-top: .5px solid black;
  border-bottom: .5px solid black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* change color of elements on mouse hover */
.dropdown_content a:hover {
  background-color:orangered;
}

/* display style of dropdown menu */
.show {
  display:grid;
}

@keyframes unfold {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: top center;
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateY(0) scaleY(1);
    transform-origin: top center;
  }
}

.unfold{
  animation: unfold 0.5s;
}

@keyframes fold {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) scaleY(1);
    transform-origin: top center;
  }
  100%{
    transform: translateY(0) scaleY(0);
    transform-origin: top center;
  }
}

.fold{
  animation: fold 0.5s;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var previousPage = null;
var currentPage = null;

function dropDown(dropdownId) {
    var dropdownContents = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown_content");
    var dropdownContent = document.getElementById(dropdownId);
    
    // close the open dropdowns on other dropdown clicks
    for (var i = 0; i < dropdownContents.length; i++) {
        var dropdown = dropdownContents[i];
        if (dropdown.classList.contains('show') && dropdown !== dropdownContent) {
            dropdown.classList.remove('show');
            dropdown.classList.remove('unfold'); 
            dropdown.classList.toggle('fold'); 
        }

    }

    dropdownContent.classList.toggle("show");
     if (dropdownContent.classList.contains('show')) {
        dropdownContent.classList.add("unfold");
        dropdownContent.classList.remove("fold");
    } else {
        dropdownContent.classList.add("fold");
        dropdownContent.classList.remove("unfold");
    }
}

window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event){
    if (event.key === 'Escape'){
        var dropdownContents = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown_content");

        for (let i=0; i < dropdownContents.length; i++){
            dropdownContent = dropdownContents[i];
            if (dropdownContent.classList.contains('show')){
                if (!dropdownContents[i].contains(event.target)){
                    dropdownContents[i].classList.remove('show');
                    dropdownContents[i].classList.toggle("fold");  
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
    else{
        pass;
    }
});

window.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
        var dropdownContents = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown_content");
        
        for (var i = 0; i < dropdownContents.length; i++) {
            var dropdownContent = dropdownContents[i];
            if (dropdownContent.classList.contains('show') && !dropdownContent.contains(event.target)) {
                dropdownContent.classList.remove('show');
                dropdownContent.classList.toggle("fold"); 
            }
        }
    }

    if (event.target.matches('.page')) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        if (event.target === currentPage) {
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = '';
            currentPage = null;
        } else {
            if (currentPage) {
                currentPage.style.backgroundColor = '';
            }
            event.target.style.backgroundColor = 'orangered';
            currentPage = event.target;
        }
    }
});

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var dropdownContents = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown_content");

    for (var i = 0; i < dropdownContents.length; i++) {
        var dropdownContent = dropdownContents[i];
        var links = dropdownContent.getElementsByTagName("a");

        // convert html to array
        var linksArray = Array.from(links);

        // numeric and alphanumeric comparison
        linksArray.sort(function(a, b) {
            var textA = a.textContent;
            var textB = b.textContent;

            // check if text ends with number
            var regex = /\d+$/;
            var matchA = textA.match(regex);
            var matchB = textB.match(regex);

            if (matchA && matchB) {
                // compare numbers
                var numberA = parseInt(matchA[0]);
                var numberB = parseInt(matchB[0]);
                if (numberA === numberB) {
                    // if numbers are equal, sort alphabetically
                    var remainingTextA = textA.slice(0, matchA.index).trim();
                    var remainingTextB = textB.slice(0, matchB.index).trim();
                    return remainingTextA.localeCompare(remainingTextB);
                } else {
                    return numberA - numberB;
                }
            } else {
                return textA.localeCompare(textB);
            }
        });

        // clear existing links to prevent bulk
        while (dropdownContent.firstChild) {
            dropdownContent.firstChild.remove();
        }

        // add back sorted links to dropdown
        for (var j = 0; j < linksArray.length; j++) {
            dropdownContent.appendChild(linksArray[j]);
        }
    }
});
```

The Javascript might have huge errors in it since I was tweaking some of it to see how I could overcome the problem.

Long story short: I want to add the opposite of an unfolding animation for when I remove display of some list elements but what I tried does not work. What am I doing wrong?